# PHP (URL) matching regex issue

Tags: php, regex, url

I'm looking for a regex to match a given URL which contains something like
`"/unknownnumber/knownstring1-unknownstring.html"`
in order to redirect it with PHP to other new url like
`"/unknownnumber/knownstring2-unknownstring"`
to keep Google indexed URLs active.

I have used next statement, but `$do_match` returns `0`, so I'm doing something wrong...

Could someone help me with my regular expression?

```
$myURL = "/unknownnumber/knownstring1-unknownstring.html";
$do_match = preg_match('~"([0-9]+)/knownstring1-(.*?)$.html"~', $myURL, $matches);
```

Comment: So `echo '<pre>';print_r($matches);echo'</pre>';exit;` is empty?

Comment: Yes, it returns an empty array, and $do_match returns 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$myURL = "/unknownnumber/knownstring1-unknownstring.html";
if(preg_match('#"/(\d+)/knownstring1-(.*)\.html"#', $myURL, $matches))
    var_dump($matches);
```

outputs:

```
php > $exp = '#"/(\d+)/knownstring1-(.*)\.html"#';
php > $str = '"/23421/knownstring1-unknownstring.html"';
php > if(preg_match($exp, $str, $matches)) var_dump($matches); else echo 'nope' .     PHP_EOL;
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(40) ""/23421/knownstring1-unknownstring.html""
  [1]=>
  string(5) "23421"
  [2]=>
  string(13) "unknownstring"
}
php >
```

Answer (score 2):

Dot (.), dash (-) are meta characters that have special meaning.

If 'unknownumber' is a numeric part of your string, then regexp pattern would looke like this:

```
$do_match = preg_match('/\/(\d+)\/knownstring1\-([^\.]+)\.html/', $input, $matches);
```

Comment: I've joint both answers (as yours gave me next message: Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash), so i used "$do_match = preg_match('~"\/(\d+)\/knownstring1\-([^\.]+)\.html/"$~', $myURL, $matches);" but... it still doesn't return any match... sorry..

Comment: Sorry, was in rush. I've fixed the pattern. It had missing preceding delimiter - forward slash in particular case. However, since you're using tildes as delimiter, the adopted pattern would look like this:`$do_match = preg_match('~\/(\d+)\/knownstring1\-([^\.]+)\.html~', $input, $matches);`

Answer (score 2):

A `$` is a end of line marker. You need to place it at the end of the regex and also to mean a literal `.` you need to escape it.

```
preg_match('~"([0-9]+)/knownstring1-(.*?)\.html"$~'....
```

Comment: Thanks for that advice, but it still doesn't return any matches... I've seen maybe my regex should be like $do_match = preg_match('~"/([0-9]+)/knownstring1-(.*?)$.html"~', $myURL, $matches); with the extra slash before the number, but it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
$myURL = "/123/knownstring1-unknownstring.html";
$do_matches = preg_match('#\/(\d+)\/(.*)\-(.*)\.html#', $myURL, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**print_r output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => /123/knownstring1-unknownstring.html
    [1] => 123
    [2] => knownstring1
    [3] => unknownstring
)
```